# HtmlAgilityPack: get all elements by class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML, and i need to get some nodes by class. So i can't do it because

1. I dunno XML path
2. Items needed has no ID, only class
3. HtmlAgilityPack do not allow to get all elements (like `XDocument` allows), but `doc.Elements()` works only if i have an id, but i haven't. So i also dunno XML path so i cannot use `SelectNodes` method
4. I cannot use regexps

my code was

```
public static class HapHelper
{
    private static HtmlNode GetByAttribute(this IEnumerable<HtmlNode> htmlNodes, string attribute, string value)
    {
        return htmlNodes.First(d => d.HasAttribute(attribute) && d.Attributes[attribute].ToString() == value);
    }

    public static HtmlNode GetElemenyByAttribute(this HtmlNode parentNode, string attribute, string value)
    {
        return GetByAttribute(parentNode.Descendants(), attribute, value);
    }

    public static bool HasAttribute(this HtmlNode d, string attribute)
    {
        return d.Attributes.Contains(attribute);
    }

    public static HtmlNode GetElementByClass(this HtmlNode parentNode, string value)
    {
        return parentNode.GetElemenyByAttribute("class", value);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't works, because `Descendants()` returns only nearest nodes.

What can I do?

Comment: XPath is the solution. Learn it!

Comment: You can start from here: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I prefer [Fizzler](http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/),it will be much easier if you understand CSS selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn XPath! :-) It's really simple, and will serve you well. In this case, what you want is:

```
SelectNodes("//*[@class='" + classValue + "']") ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>();
```

Comment: +1. Note that if you want JQuery-like selector (class contains given value) you need to use [`.contains`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304265) function.